# What is the state of a particle given the state of system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

I've just started to learn about application of tensor product in quantum mechanics. I've a small doubt. Please help me.

If we've a  system of two particles, and its state is given by a tensor product of  $|x\rangle \otimes |y\rangle$ where  $|x\rangle$ belongs to the first particle's Hilbert space  $H_1$ and $|y\rangle$ belongs to $H_2$

Then can I say that the first particle is in state $|x\rangle$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is indeed what the tensor product state $|x\rangle\otimes|y\rangle$ means: the first particle is in the $|x\rangle$ state, and the second particle is in the $|y\rangle$ state.

Although, this is for distinguishable particles, where you can clearly say 'this is the first particle, this is the second,' etc.

Comment: Thank you. If the state of the whole system is an entangled one then we can't say that one particle is in this state and other is in this?

Comment: Correct. In an entangled system $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ are no longer eigenstates of the system.